# Short query for this long one

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Can anybody please tell me shortest query for this :

```
        var guestpartyids = db.CeremonyGuestParties.Where(p => p.CeremonyId == id)
                           .Select(p => p.GuestPartyId);
        List<GuestParty> guestparties = new List<GuestParty>();
        foreach (var party in guestpartyids)
        {
            guestparties.Add(db.GuestParties.Single(p => p.Id == party));
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do it.

```
guestparties.AddRange(
  from cgp in db.CeremonyGuestParties
  where cgp.CeremonyId == id
  join gp in db.GuestParties on cgp.GuestPartyId equals gp.Id
  select gp
);
```

Please note that this will result in one database call, as where your code will result in 1+N queries. But it will not ensure there's only one matching ID, like Single() would do. This should be enforced on the database anyway, and not in code.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
List<GuestParty> guestparties = from cgp in db.CeremonyGuestParties.
                                Where cgp.CeremonyId .id == id) 
                                select cgp.Guestparties.ToList();
```